# Add and save item to favorites

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a tableview with many words and I want to add the favorites feature so each detail view can have a button to save as a Favorite. This is my code, but doesn't work, after pressing the button I get this error (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType'), but if I use slovoItem.slovo or slovoItem.definice, value is saved correctly. slovoItem has values slovoItem.slovo and slovoItem.definice and I need to save completely slovoItem.

**Code in my DetailViewController:**

```
- (IBAction) addToFavorites:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[prefs objectForKey:@"favorite"] mutableCopy];
    favorite = tempArray;

    [favorite addObject:self.slovoItem];

    [prefs setObject:favorite forKey:@"favorite"];

    for (id obj in favorite)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Objects cannot be written to user defaults, only the types NSString, NSData, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray and NSDictionary. The container types must contain items of the 6 allowed types.

The usual way to save custom types is to conform to the NSCoding protocol.
In the @interface line add the protocol

```
 @interface SlovoItem : NSObject <NSCoding> {
```

In the .m file you must implement `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` methods:

```
  - (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
  {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
      self.slovo = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"slovo"];
      self.definice = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"definice"];
    }
    return self;
  }

  - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
  {
    [coder encodeObject:self.slovo forKey:@"slovo"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.definice forKey:@"definice"];
  }
```

now you can save a custom type with

```
  - (IBAction) addToFavorites:(id)sender
  {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *favorite = [[defaults objectForKey:@"favorite"] mutableCopy];
    [favorite addObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.slovoItem]];
    [defaults setObject:favorite forKey:@"favorite"];
  }
```

The archiver encodes the custom type to an NSData object

The code is an example and not tested. There might be typos

Comment: Thx but it doesnt work, because my class DetailViewInteface is not a NSObject :-(. My class is @interface DetailViewController (). I'm sorry, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: But as you have a slovoItem object with two properties I strongly recommend to create a custom class for this type

Comment: My application load data from XML to UITableView and then to DetailViewController. So maybe I need to save favorites only the index and then reload correct index in the UITableView (Favorits tab). I do not know :(

Comment: Vadian, can I contact you to your e-mail pls? Because I need really help. Thx

Comment: we could talk in a chat room

Comment: Ok can you invite me to chat? I have no experience with that

Comment: Neither have I, I'll try it